# How do I force nmcli to reconnect to different uuid?

Tags: wireless, networking, bash, scripts, network-manager

I have a bash script that checks my network environment and mounts shares accordingly.  If I'm at work and have a hard-wire connection to the LAN, then I'd like to activate a hotspot connection for the wireless devices in my office.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# are we at home?
if [ "$(ping -q -c1 00.00.00.00)" ]; then
  mount <home shares>
# well then are we on campus?
elif [ "$(ping -q -c1 00.00.00.00)" ]; then
  mount <work shares>
  # if we're on campus, then are we connected to an ethernet cable?
  if [ "$(nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep GENERAL.CONNECTION)" != "GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     not connected" ]; then
  nmcli con up uuid <uuid> iface wlan0
  fi
fi
```

The nmcli command fails; there are several problems.

The nmcli tool doesn't seem to allow disconnecting a wireless connection arbitrarily.  You can do `nmcli con down` but only if you can specify the `<id>` or `<uuid>`.  In my environment wlan0 will connect to one of several wireless networks somewhat arbitrarily.

The `nmcli dev disconnect` works with a specified `<iface>` but seems to prevent reconnecting to anything except by manual selection.  Reconnecting in a bash script doesn't seem to work.

The `nmcli con up` command (currently in the script above) doesn't seem to work if the `<iface>` has already established a connection.

Any suggestions on how to use `nmcli` to force a specified `<uuid>` connection when an unspecified `<uuid>` connection has already been established?  Would something besides nmcli would work better?

Thanks!

Comment: What about cycling `nm`? `nmcli nm enable false; nmcli nm enable true`?

Comment: This page could help: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript

Comment: How about `nmcli networking off;sleep 2;nmcli networking on`

Comment: @waltinator. thanks for that nmcli networking off, it works splendidly for me without sudo needed in 20.04.01 for off AND on, when I often have had to reboot to get the connection back up after using ifconfig down, as well as ifconfig giving me permission errors even though I had set privileges in sudooers for that and the script . I am using these for a script to disconnect when my tun0 from ifconfig goes down when VPN is lost.(their killswitch does not work). also changing usb ethernet gives different names for the connection so your way is best by far.

Comment: as usual I spoke too soon, sometimes nmcli networking on does not bring up a disconnected eth0 connection ("it is the ubuntu way").